# NullPointerException when closing app

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a bubble level app that I am trying to incorporate into another app I wrote. The app works as it should, except when you push the android back button, it force closes the app with the following exception:

Logcat:

```
04-08 08:10:15.056: I/SensorManager(21015): Set normal delay = true
04-08 08:10:15.287: W/dalvikvm(21015): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ca7ac8)
04-08 08:10:15.287: E/AndroidRuntime(21015): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-89255
04-08 08:10:15.287: E/AndroidRuntime(21015): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 08:10:15.287: E/AndroidRuntime(21015):    at com.golfstuff.ecolevel.MoveSkater$DrawSkater.run(MoveSkater.java:121)
04-08 08:10:15.287: E/AndroidRuntime(21015):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Movescater:

```
package com.golfstuff.ecolevel;
// STAND-ALONE
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class MoveSkater extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, OnTouchListener {

Bitmap level, logo, ball, lines,background, exit;
SensorManager sm;
DrawSkater ourView;
MediaPlayer beepl,beepr;
//private Camera cameraObj;
float x,y,sensorX, sensorY,mid,exitx,exity;
boolean isRunning;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check for Accelerometer
    beepl = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beepleft);
    beepr = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beepright);
    ourView = new DrawSkater(this);
    ourView.resume();
    ourView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if(sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() !=0) {
        Sensor s=sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        sm.registerListener(this,  s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }
    lines=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lines);
    level=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.newlevel);
    logo=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ecolevel);
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.newball);
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.levelback);
    exit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_exit);
    x = y = sensorX = sensorY = 0;

    setContentView(ourView);


}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sensorX=event.values[1];
    sensorY=event.values[0];

}

public class DrawSkater extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning = true;

    public DrawSkater(Context context) {

        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
    }

    public void pause() {
        isRunning = false;
        while(true) {
            try {
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 finish();
            }
              break;
        } 
        ourThread = null;

    } 

    public void resume() {
        isRunning = true;
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(isRunning) {
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                      canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); *** JAVA ERROR POINT ***
            canvas.drawBitmap(background, canvas.getWidth()/2-640,canvas.getHeight()/2-200,null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(logo, canvas.getWidth()/2-230,0,null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(level, canvas.getWidth()/2-605,canvas.getHeight()-130,null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(exit, 20,140,null);
            mid = ((sensorX*(-100))+600);
            // Right Side Max
            if (mid > 757) {
                mid = 757;

            } //Left Side Max
            else if (mid <422) {
                mid = 422;
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(ball, mid,494,null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(lines,575,497,null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(lines,653,497,null);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            // Left Center Tone
            if ((mid > 570 && mid<580)) {
                //beepl.start();


            }
            // Right Center Tone
            else if (mid >600 && mid<610) {
                //beepr.start();
            }

        }
    } 

}
```

I've tried in the onPause method:  stop();  interupt();  finish();

Also tried:  onDestroy method

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: the error is at 125 (MoveSkater.java:125), 133 is in the timestamp part of logcat

Comment: post line 125 of MoveSkater.java please

Comment: Run the app in debug mode, and set a breakpoint at the line where the null pointer occurs. This will help you work out why it's happening.

Comment: The error line noted in the CODE is the correct point of the error. LogCat line is before I deleted "//bunch of comments".

Comment: Any more ideas? Please?